# ¿Cómo integrar mi propio chat en cualquier sitio web como un widget?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, python, css

Hola muy buenas tardes.

Tengo problemas para integrar un chat que he diseñado en html y Python. Básicamente, el chat es una interfaz controlada por una serie de eventos y animaciones en javascript y jQuery, donde el usuario hace ciertas preguntas relacionadas a un tema en específico (según el cliente y obviamente con su permiso para colocar el código en su Landing page por ejemplo) y el chat, mediante un previo “entrenamiento”, le proporciona respuestas, de acuerdo con sus preguntas. Utilizo Python para todo lo relacionado con back y las respuestas que el chat proporciona. El chat funciona muy bien, pero me gustaría poder integrarlo a cualquier sitio web que lo necesite como un servicio, tal cual lo hace Facebook con su chat, zopim, zendesk y en general cualquier otro chat. Por lo que he podido leer, la mayoría de estos chats, desarrollan un script (javascript) mediante el cual, al agregarlo al sitio web solicitante, el chat se presenta de forma embebida, y eso es justo lo que estoy buscando.

Actualmente la estructura de mi chat es algo similar a esto:

CHAT.HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
    // Referencia a los css del chat
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="chat">
    <div class="titulo"></div>
    <div class="mensajes-box">
      <div class="mensaje" data-mensaje="1"></div>
      <div class="mensaje" data-mensaje="2"></div>
      ..................
    </div>
    <div class="mensaje-input">
      <input type="text"><button type="submit">enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

// Referencia a los .js que contienen los enventos (Submit, Click, agregar animacion para entrada del globo de texto, etc).  
</body>
</html>
```

Diganos que ese seria la estructura de mi "chat.html" donde puedo utilizar mi chat sin problemas.

Desde ya, agradezco todas sus respuestas.

Comment: Es verdad que la técnica del script que comentas es mejor que usar un iframe pero ¿realmente deseas hacerlo así? Si cargas el contenido en la misma página, entonces corres el riesgo de que tu chat no se vea como deseas dado que estás usando clases e ids muy comunes (las palabras chat, titulo, mensaje ... son muy comunes). Es muy posible que tus estilos y los estilos del sitio colisionen. Con el iframe no pasa, pero el iframe es un dolor de muelas para los sitios responsive. Te recomiendo que uses un prefijo para tus clases (chat-edwin-mensaje en lugar de mensaje, por ejemplo)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario Roberto. La estructura de mi html, de mis etiquetas no es la mencionada, es "algo así", por ejemplo donde coloco ".chat" realmente es "py-chatbot-holder" por lo cual entiendo tu punto y ya lo había previsto, no creo que exista una colisión de estilos. Otro detalle a mencionar es que en estos "scripts" que se usan para crear estas widgets, si inspeccionas su contenido, siempre acaban creando el iframe, pero obviamente bajo este método (el cual deseo aprender) y no la típica etiqueta iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para empezar, como anotación, me gustaría saber mas acerca de tu código para que pudieses dar una imagen mas clara de cual es el problema, para eso te dejo esta ayuda... [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Ya que para lo que requieres, es necesario saber como vas a hospedar tu código sobre todo en Python, aun así espero que te sea de ayuda la siguiente información!.

> Primero creemos el código.
>
> CSS y HTML:

Me tome la libertad de hacer por mi propia cuenta el estilo del chat, pero este no funciona, solo es un ejemplo.

```css
* {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;

}

#chat {

  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 30px;
  border-radius: 12px;

}

.title {

  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(81, 138, 158);
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;

}

.title h1 {

  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;

}

.input-box {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(195, 195, 195);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;

}

.input-box input {

  height: 25px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  background-color: rgb(81, 138, 158);
  border: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  color: white;

}

.input-box button {

  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 35px;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(81, 138, 158);
  color: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;

}

.mssage-box {

  width: 180px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.message-oside {

  float: left;
  max-width: 90%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
  padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
  color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;

}

.message-myside {

  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 80%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(81, 138, 158);
  padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chat">
      <div class="title">
          <h1>Team</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mssage-box">
        <div class="message-oside" data-mensaje="1">Hi how are you?, If you have any doubts, let me know please!</div>
      <div class="message-myside" data-mensaje="2">Hi</div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text"><button type="submit">→</button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Antes de proceder tenemos que hospedar los archivos que creamos, los puedes hospedar en cualquier proveedor de hosting tradicional, pero yo lo hice en [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/), mas adelante explico porque. También puedes hacer esto con [DriveToWeb](https://drv.tw).

Ahora creamos el archivo .js que queremos ofrecer para introducir el código.

> Jquery

En este caso es bastante simple, tal vez necesites encriptar o proteger este archivo pero para lo que necesitas, es funcional, y sin `iframe`.

Con `.load()` cargamos el archivo de la fuente externa donde esta el código, en este caso, como mencione antes, utilizo Github para hospedar los archivos que necesito y a demás solo llamo del documento la id `#chat` ya que como ves arriba es el nombre que le colocamos a la etiqueta. También introduzco dentro de el `head` un nuevo `link` que contiene la ruta remota del la hoja de estilos que necesita nuestro nuevo html (Explicado mas adelante).

```
$("body").load("https://denyncrawford.github.io/index.html #chat");

$("head").html('<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://denyncrawford.github.io/main.css">');
```

Para poder ofrecer un producto que se integre a través de un enlace o `<script></script>` necesitas tener el el archivo hospedado (en este caso nuestro nuevo`JavaScript`). Para ofrecer el enlace a el mismo, puedes hospedarlo de manera tradicional o con Github/Drive, en este caso lo introduje dentro de la misma rama Git de antes ya que podemos obtener nuestro propio CDN gracias a [Rawgit](https://rawgit.com/), solo copiamos en enlace de nuestro archivo del repositorio de Github en este caso el mio es https://github.com/denyncrawford/denyncrawford.github.io/blob/master/get.js y lo pegamos en la barra de Rawgit, esta herramienta nos proporciona dos enlaces, el de producción y el de desarrollo.

> **ACTUALIZACIÓN**

**Rawgit** **ha sido descontinuada**, puedes hacer lo mismo con [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/).

Ahora solo falta implementarlo, nuestro `script`. Este deberia quedar de la siguiente manera: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/denyncrawford/denyncrawford.github.io/b98806d6/get.js"> </script>`

A continuación lo usaremos en nuestra pagina o la pagina del cliente (observar en pagina completa).

```html
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Nuestro srcipt con el CDN -->
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/denyncrawford/denyncrawford.github.io@b98806d6b090a2540b9d24e368005b6b4f4de6c2/get.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Podemos observar que nuestro código ya esta inyectado en la pagina con solo el `script` que nosotros proporcionamos.

Ahora, en cuanto al .py no sabría como esta construido, pero aun así espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Buena respuesta :), quizás sería bueno comentar que el código a implementar en python sea un controlador que reciba una petición HTTP GET y devuelva la respuesta con el contenido del script :)

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por sus respuestas.
Dєηyη Crawford, me parece muy buena tu respuesta y creo que si podría ayudarme. El código py, pues en general lo tengo todo de forma local por lo que el py recibe lo que se va agregando al chat, lo interpreta y emite una respuesta. Aun no tenia contemplado como hostearlo pero con tu respuesta me has dado una muy buena línea de acción. Probare con lo que me dices y en caso de no conseguir un resultado exitoso, me daré a la tarea de crear un ejemplo mucho mas completo y real del problema. Muchas gracias,Saludos Cordiales.

Comment: Me alegro de que sirva, me gustaría seguir el hilo del trabajo que realizas, gracias a tu pregunta me puse a trabajar en un sistema de generador de llaves para crear salas de chat y usuarios, para una solución de chat en vivo... jeje si te interesa el hilo, espero que pronto este en mi repositorio de github! para que le eches un ojo!