# Como enviar canvas mediante ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Queria enviar un canvas que tengo en un html a otro mediante canvas, el codigo de ajax es este:

```
function ajax(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            respuesta(this.responseText);  
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "Snake.html", true);
    xhttp.send(); 
}

function respuesta(respuesta){
    var contenido=document.createElement("div");
    contenido.innerHTML=respuesta;
    var quiero=contenido.getElementsByClassName("canvas");
    document.getElementById("principal").innerHTML=quiero[0];
}
```

el html del cual se extrae el canvas es el siguiente:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script src="Snake.js"></script>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>  

    </body>
</html>
```

Eesto es lo que se envia:`[object HTMLCanvasElement]`

Comment: Realmente, ¿qué es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: @PabloLozano quiero hacer una landing page con juegos, y que cunado pinches en uno mediante ajax te devuelva el canvas del mismo y puedes jugar, asi no tienes porque cargar todos los scrips de los juegos.

Comment: Has intentado con iframe?, mira mi respuesta en [esta pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194692/c%c3%b3mo-integrar-mi-propio-chat-en-cualquier-sitio-web-como-un-widget/194801#194801)

Comment: @parrado Lamentablemente eso no te va a funcionar, son los scripts lo que hacen que el juego funcione. El canvas es, como su propio nombre indica, un [lienzo](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=canvas) donde los scripts dibujan e interactúan.

Comment: A lo mejor esta respuesta te puede ayudar: [Mostrar contenido en mi body, con JS
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197603/mostrar-contenido-en-mi-body-con-js/197615#197615)

Comment: @PabloLozano interpreto por tu respuesta que al extraer el canvas mediante ajax no me incluye el script asociado a dicho documento. Sabiendo mi finalidad que es elegir cuando cargar un script, se te ocurre alguna solucion o simplemente redirecciono a otro html?

Comment: @parrado Redirecciona o usa un iframe. En cualquier caso carga el juego en una página propia, porque Javascript da muchos problemas a la hora de *cerrar* un juego. Si se cambia de juego, lo ideal es cargar una nueva página